# Dejar girando loader

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola buenos días tengo el diseño de un loader el cual se ejecuta cuando se esta cargando la página, pero ahora lo que intento hacer es utilizar ese mismo diseño para otros movimientos por ejemplo mientras que se genera un reporte dejarlo girando para cuando termine de generarse el reporte detenerlo, prácticamente algo así estoy intentando hacer, pero no me queda no se quiere mostrar el loader. Les comparto mi código.

> Loader

```js
var carga = document.getElementById('contenedor_carga').visibility = 'visible';
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    *,*:affter, *:before{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      #contenedor_carga{
        background-color: rgba(250, 240, 245, 1);
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;

        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      #carga{
        border: 15px solid #ccc;
        border-top-color: #80be51;
        border-top-style: groove;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 100%;

        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;

        -webkit-animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
        -0-animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
        animation: girar 1.5s linear infinite;
      }

      @keyframes girar {
        from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
  </style>
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_carga">
    <div id="carga">
      
    </div>
</div>
```

***Cuando entre al 2do if requiero ejecutar el loader pero no lo hace***

```js
if (date_inicio.length > 0 && date_fin.length > 0) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Estás seguro?',
        text: "No podrás revertir esto!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Continuar',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            var carga = document.getElementById('contenedor_carga').visibility = 'visible';
        }
      })

      // searchAlumnosAjax(date_inicio, date_fin);
    } else {
      fecha_inicio.classList.add("is-invalid");
      fecha_fin.classList.add("is-invalid");
    }
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias.

Comment: debes acceder al style del mismos ejemplo: `var carga = document.getElementById('contenedor_carga').style.visibility = 'visible'; ` para que pueda cambiarlo. lo otro que recomiendo es utilizar la propiedad `display:none;` ya que `visibility` solo oculta el elemento pero seguira ocupando el espacio que le corresponde dentro del `dom`

Comment: coloque el código que me compartiste y sigue sin funcionar var carga = document.getElementById('contenedor_carga').style.visibility = 'visible';

Comment: no ps si quieres ocultar obviamente no es `visible` si no hidden :V

Comment: osheeeee!! no lo quiero ocultar, quiero que se muestre pero no lo hace

Comment: sigo sin entender lo que quieres?? si en tu codigo este siempre se muestra para que quieres volverlo a mostrar? :v

Comment: Al cargar una pagina se ejecuta load y despues se muestra la pagina ya cargada. Quiero ocupar ese mismo load que ya esta echo para cuando presione un boton se muestre muentras yo por dentro hago operaciones, lo quiero dejar cargando mientras finaliza el proceso.